# Cannot get Mobile version of website to render in WebdriverIO

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to get the Mobile version of my web page to render in WebdriverIO, but instead, the desktop version is loaded.

I have used the following statement in the test script: `browser.setWindowSize(width, height);`. The browser opens with the given `width` and `height`, but the desktop web page is loaded instead mobile web page

I have used the below statement in test script
`browser.setWindowSize(411, 823);`

**❯ Expected results:** Mobile version of the website should be rendered

**❯ Actual results:** Desktop version of the website is rendered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, from what I understand, you want to run mobile tests and you assumed that by resizing the browser window, it will somehow trigger the mobile view?! That's not how it works.

I see two straightforward approaches:

**1.** We emulate the mobiles device in Chrome. We manage this by enabling the **[Mobile Emulation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation)** feature via **Chrome DevTools**. You will have to specify *a custom user-agent* & *the device type*
    in your `chromeOptions` via the `mobileEmulation` property:

---

❒ **wdio.conf.js:**

```
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 1,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        mobileEmulation: {'deviceName': 'Nexus 5'},
        args: [ '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--start-fullscreen',
                '--disable-notifications',
                //
                '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
                 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
        ]
    }
}],
```

This will create a mobile emulation in your Chrome instance, enabling the mobile logic to take effect. Then, you can proceed with your mobile-specific checks.

**!Notes:**

- if you're running `wdio-v5` (*WebdriverIOv5*) => add your Chrome options inside the `goog:chromeOptions` object
- if you're running `wdio-v4` (*WebdriverIOv4*) => add your Chrome options inside the `chromeOptions` object
- `deviceName` examples: `'iPhone 7'`, `'iPhone X'`, `'iPad Mini'`, `'Galaxy S5'`, etc.
- you can find a complete list of `user-agents` [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) (*Chrome*), or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) (*Firefox*)

---

**2.** We use **Appium** to simulate our mobile devices. We will have to install the [@wdio/appium-service](https://webdriver.io/docs/appium-service.html) WebdriverIO plugin.

If you haven't worked with [Appium](http://appium.io/) before, then
    [THIS](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate) is a
    really nice **WebdriverIO/Appium** boilerplate project, so you don't
    have to start from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked with little modification by changing the `chromeOptions` to `goog:chromeOptions`.